# Is it possible to use card.io library for hybrid applications?

Tags: javascript, hybrid-mobile-app, scanning, card.io

I know that card.io library helps in scanning credit/debit card for native applications.
Is it possible to use this library for hybrid applications to retrieve card details?
Can anyone suggest some other opensource library for the same function?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the card.io community supported PhoneGap project.  See the [iOS](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK-PhoneGap) project for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Check this Cordova Plugin. It is available for android and iOS

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-keepe-cardio

Comment: Thanks for the response